# Convert decimal integer to hex in Elixir

Tags: hex, elixir

I know we can declare an integer in base 2, 8, 10, or 16, for example:

```
0b10000
0o20
16
0x10
```

all result in the integer `16`.

But given an integer, for example `43981`, how do I get its hexadecimal representation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Integer.to_string/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#to_string/2) with `16` as the second argument.

```elixir
Integer.to_string(43981, 16) # "ABCD"
```

You can also get the binary and octal representations the same way:

```elixir
Integer.to_string(43981, 2) # "1010101111001101"
Integer.to_string(43981, 8) # "125715"
```